# How many concurrent rtsp streams can live555 stream over the WAN reliably

Tags: c++, live555

I have written a rtsp ondemand server in C++ using live555 and I am able to host a rtsp stream.  I then used VLC to connect to the server through the WAN and the image streams and looks great.  Then I went to another computer and connected to the rtsp stream, I am seeing that both videos become choppy.

The data is h264 compressed and the resolution of the image is 800x600.  The symptoms looks like there isnt enough bandwidth?

Basically my question is how many concurrent rtsp connections can be done over the WAN with live555.  Has anyone else been able to stream reliably over the WAN using live555?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly dependent on your WAN up-link bandwidth and your video bit-rate.

Let's try to estimate bit-rate of your given video. A very good explanation can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5024114/suggested-compression-ratio-with-h-264) Assuming a moderate level of motion and  30 fps video this results in 3 mbps (800 x 600 x 30 x 3 x 0.07) bit-rate in your case. So if your up-link BW is less than 6 mbps, you cannot stream 2 videos simultaneously.

Other than that, live555 doesn't have any hard-coded limitations on this regard.